# Send strings in recyclerview item's text views to new fragment and start that fragment activity on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This is my view holder class inside adapter class which is a separate class file. The recycler view is shown in a fragment and on click of the recycler view item I need to go to a new fragment activity and get the texts that was shown in the clicked item

```
    public class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public final BookRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

        private TextView titleTextView, authorTextView;

public BookViewHolder(View itemView, BookRecyclerAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);

            titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_title_tView);
            authorTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_author_tView);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

private void setBookCardView(String tText, String aText){

            titleTextView.setText(tText);
            authorTextView.setText(aText);
        }

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String title = titleTextView.getText().toString();
            String author = authorTextView.getText().toString();
//I NEED TO PASS THIS STRINGS TO NEW FRAGMENT
}
}
```

How can a start a new fragment activity which can access these two strings - title and author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onClick method of the view holder class

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
bundle.putString("key", "value");
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
secondFragment.setArguments(bundle);
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, secondFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

After this you can start to retrieve the data in the fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
  String strtext=getArguments().getString("string1"); //fetching value by key
  String strtext1=getArguments().getString("string2"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Bundle** to pass data adapter to fragment in your click Listener

```
 Fragment fragment = new FragmentName();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getSupportFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("string1", "your string");
bundle.putString("string2", "your string"); //key and value
    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and retrieve data in fragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
  String strtext=getArguments().getString("string1"); //fetching value by key
  String strtext1=getArguments().getString("string2"); 
    }
```

Comment: Cant resolve symbol context. I am not in any activity, im in my adapter class

Comment: pass the activity context to adapter constructor and use that context in adapter

Answer (score 1):

In the view holder class onClick:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
bundle.putString("key", "value");
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
secondFragment.setArguments(bundle);
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, secondFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In the recieving fragment

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            Snackbar.make(view, bundle.get("key").toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```